# condaコマンドが使えない

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

PCはmacbookProです。

anancondaインストール後一度削除し、再インストールしてからcondaコマンドが使えなくなってしまいました。何度か再インストールもしくはanacondaの完全な削除を試みたのですが、どうもわかりません。

再インストール時のやり方としてはGUIで進めていきました。
https://weblabo.oscasierra.net/python-anaconda-install-macos/
このサイトのやり方を参考にしました。

現在の挙動としてはcommand not found: conda　と表示されます。

また.bash_profile にはexport PATH=$PATH"1/HOME/.pyenv/shims
と書かれています。python３をデフォルトにするために書いたもののみです。

お力をお貸しください。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問 [anacondaの外で環境構築したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/51002/) にも回答しましたが、最近、Anacondaは、デフォルトでは`.bash_profile`にPATHを追加しなくなりました。PATHを追加するとシステムの実行ファイルを乗っ取ってしまってトラブルの原因になるので`.bash_profile`にPATHを追加することは望ましくないからです。

Macの場合は、Launchpadをみてください。Anaconda-Navigator等がインストールされていませんか。そこから使用するのが基本になります。

ターミナルから`conda`を使用したい場合は、次のようにAnacondaの環境を起動する必要があります。以下はユーザー(taro)のホームディレクトリにanacondaをインストールした場合です。

```
. ~/anaconda3/bin/activate
```

Anaconda が推奨しているのは、`~/.bash_profile`に、次のように設定して、`conda`　が動作するようにすることです。（参照 [Release notes 4.4.0](https://conda.io/docs/release-notes.html#id71)）

```
. /Users/taro/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
```

Anaconda推奨の`conda.sh`でなく、以下のようにエイリアスを設定しても大丈夫です。こちらは、以前から使えていました。下の例では、`conda_activate`としていますが、他のコマンドと当たらなければ`ca`というような短い名前をつけることができるので便利です。

```
alias conda_activate=". /Users/taro/anaconda3/bin/activate"
```

※注意：bash_profile にある export PATH=$PATH"1/HOME/.pyenv/shims は、トラブルの原因になるだけなので削除しましょう。Anacondaを本家からダウンロードしてインストールしたらもう`pyenv`を使う必要はないでしょう。